# integrate symfony wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony

I'm trying to integrate a Symfony 4.3 PHP app in WordPress,
By integrating I mean that the Symfony page call the get_header() and get_footer()

So I managed this by putting

```
   require dirname(__DIR__) . '../../wp-load.php';
```

in my config/bootstrap.php, and then call the WordPress functions in my controller's code.
This worked fine in the staging site, but when I got to production I got a conflict with wp rocket.
I believe this will happen in the future with other plugins or other core updates.

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare interface Psr\Container\ContainerInterface, because the name is already in use in /home/avporg/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-rocket/vendor/psr/container/src/ContainerInterface.php on line 11
```

How can I correct this error?